# Lambda is not detecting the prefix path when I create cloud watch event to my S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am working with **.csv files** like whenever **.csv file** is uploaded in **S3 bucket** then **lambd**a should automatically trigger that and reads the content inside the .csv file. To achieve this I created one **S3 trigger event** to my bucket and connected to Lambda function.

**Folder Structure :**

Bucket name : **synched-data**

inside bucket there will be two directories **c0:ee:40:39:96:e8** and **csv data**

inside these two directories there will be another directory called **Backup**
inside Backup directory we will upload .csv files

But if I create trigger event to my S3 bucket with prefix path **c0:ee:40:39:96:e8/Backup** to my lambda function then trigger is not working Lambda is not detecting and not reading my .csv file whenever I upload

But if I create trigger event with prefix path **csvdata/Backup** then trigger is working and Lambda is detecting and reading my csv data

So here **my question is** why trigger is not working and Lambda is unable to read and detect the data when directory name is like this **c0:ee:40:39:96:e**8 ? and if I want this to be done what should I do ? Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Colons are special characters that might need special handling: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html

Comment: Personally, I'd report this to AWS as a bug and see what the response is. It's not clear how the "might need special handling of colons" advisory would actually be accomplished here. I created a simple repro for this and the bucket event notification appears to be setup correctly and shows the correct prefix, an upload to a key under the prefix c0:ee:40:39:96:e8/backup/ works correctly and results in the correct key, but the Lambda function does not appear to be triggered.

Comment: If you attempt to escape the colon with %3A, for example by uploading to c0%3Aee%3A40%3A39%3A96%3Ae8/backup/, then the %3A is not unescaped (at least when using the awscli to upload). Alternatively, modifying the event configuration to trigger on the escaped prefix c0%3Aee%3A40%3A39%3A96%3Ae8/backup/ doesn't work either.

Comment: Ditto if you hex-escape the colon to `&#x3a` in either the upload or the bucket notification configuration. So, unclear how and where to escape this. Probably worth considering not using a mac address (?) as a key prefix but create your own variant of it, e.g. strip the colons or replace with hyphens.